# Test a weak reference before using it java

Tags: java, android, weak-references

In a multithreaded Android project, I'm seeing code like this:

```
final WeakReference<MyClass> myClassObjectWeakRef =
                new WeakReference<MyClass>(aMyClassObject);
```

...then somewhere else:

```
if (myClassObjectWeakRef.get() != null) {
  myClassObjectWeakRef.get().someMethod();
}
```

I'm pretty sure there is a possible race condition between the check and the use of the reference, if the last strong reference to the object is released between the two in another thread, but I can't find any documentation or anyone which/who can confirm this better than with a "you're probably right".

I would think the only right way to test & use a weak reference is done like this:

```
MyClass myObject = myClassObjectWeakRef.get();
// we now have a strong reference, or null: standard checks apply.
if (myObject != null) {
  myObject.someMethod();
}
```

I'm very confident that the second method is 100% safe, but I wonder if there is some Java/compiler sugar/magic that I don't know about, which would make the first method safe.

So, is the first method 100% safe, or not?

Comment: you're probably right, ;-)

Comment: There shouldn't be any built-in java/compiler sugar/magic to ensure method #1 will always work. Your understanding of the situation matches my understanding of the situation as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first method is definitely unsafe. Each call to `get` is independent. There is nothing preventing the GC from clearing the weakly reachable object after the first `get` and before the second.

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) states

> Suppose that the garbage collector determines **at a certain point in
>   time** that an object is weakly reachable. At that time it will
>   atomically clear all weak references to that object and all weak
>   references to any other weakly-reachable objects from which that
>   object is reachable through a chain of strong and soft references.

That can be at any point in time. Calling `get()`, which (potentially) pushes a reference to the object on the stack temporarily makes the object strongly reachable (it's on a thread's stack), but that reach-ability disappears the moment the comparison with `null` finishes. After that moment, the GC can determine that the object is weakly reachable and clear its reference. You'd then get a `NullPointerException`.

Use your second method. But note that by assigning it to a variable, you are making the referenced object strongly reachable.